# Angular ui-sortable - issue when draggable element comes from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I have 2 columns: left and right. The flow is to drag elements from the left column and drop it into the right one.
It works perfectly, but there is a small issue: when draggable element comes to droppable area from the top, the placeholder is shown as a last element of existing items list in droppable area. I can drag my current draggable item a bit downer, then drag it over that element again and placeholder will be shown in the right way.
Question: how do I show the placeholder as a 0th element (not last) of items list if draggable element comes from the top? In which direction should I dig? Thanks a lot.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I figured it out by myself.
I have add several fields to existing objects:

for draggable:

```
snap: true,
snapTolerance: 0,
tolerance: 'pointer'
```

for droppable and sortable:

```
tolerance: 'pointer'
```

Make sure that helper and placeholder have margins set to 0 (you can do it inside the directive or in css).
Hope it will be useful for someone.